# using plumber package in Rscript and running script from cmd

Tags: r, command-line, plumber

In my Rscript (run.R):

```
library(plumber)
r <- plumb("script.R")
r$run(host="127.0.0.1",port=8000)
```

If I run the above code using RStudio or R console it works fine and gives me access after following output:

> Starting server to listen on port 8000 Running the swagger UI at
>   [http://127.0.0.1:8000/**swagger**/](http://127.0.0.1:8000/__swagger__/)

but when I try to run the same code as a .R file using Rscript, R CMD BATCH,R < run.R, pm2 it gets stuck at;

> Starting server to listen on port 8000

and on accessing address I get 404: Resource Not Found Error. Also, note that I want to run this on windows therefore didn't try littler. Any idea, what I am doing wrong here. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`run` takes a `swagger` argument that defaults to `interactive()`. i.e. it only enables swagger if you're running interactively.

You can hardcode this to `TRUE` if you want Swagger to be enabled on your router even when run programmatically.

```
r$run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8000, swagger=TRUE)
```